# qq,Fileuploader change params attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

I am using qq.fileuploader in my project it works fine onload, but if I want to update the params attribute on change of a dropdown, it gives errors.

```
var _thisId = jQuery('#qq-uploader_csv_1');

var _params_str = _thisId.attr('qq-params');

var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('qq-uploader_csv_1'),
    action: _gDocRoot+'uploadCSV.php',
    debug: false,
    params: jQuery.parseJSON(_params_str),
    multiple: _thisId.attr('qq-multiple'),
    allowedExtensions: upAllow,

     onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
        alert(responseJSON);

     }
});    

jQuery('#arc_table').on('change', function(){
    var table_id = jQuery('option:selected',this).val();

     _params_str = '&quot;module&quot;:&quot;csv&quot;,&quot;rec_id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;slot&quot;:1,&quot;order_no&quot;:1,&quot;multiple&quot;:false,&quot;arc_tbl&quot;:&quot;'+ table_id +'&quot;';

    uploader.setParams(jQuery.parseJSON(_params_str));
});
```

Please help me in fixing this issue.